# Node.js некорректно работает колбэк на чтение файла

Tags: javascript, node.js

Почему код (Node.JS), указанный ниже, выдает в консоль только первую строку файла?

```
var fs = require("fs");

var writeableStream = fs.createWriteStream("hello.txt");
writeableStream.write("Привет мир!");
writeableStream.write("Продолжение записи \n");
writeableStream.end("Завершение записи");
var readableStream = fs.createReadStream("hello.txt", "utf8");

// Эта часть кода выдает только первую строку файла
readableStream.on("data", function(chunk){ 
    console.log(chunk);
});
```

Comment: Событие `data` возникает неоднократно во время чтения. Событие, происходящее после всего чтения, называется `end`.

Comment: Вы делаете что-то странное и, подозреваю, что файл открылся на чтение раньше, чем туда всё записалось. Что вы хотите сделать-то?

Comment: Дружище, странное делаешь только ты, а этот код взят из курса обучения с сайта metanit.com.

Comment: Ну такой вот хреновый учебник.

Answer (score 3):

Запись файла происходит асинхронно и что бы быть точно уверенным, что запись закончилась надо слушать событие `close` у `writableStream`.

Вот так всё работает.

```
var fs = require("fs");

var writeableStream = fs.createWriteStream("hello.txt");
writeableStream.write("Привет мир!");
writeableStream.write("Продолжение записи \n");
writeableStream.end("Завершение записи");

writeableStream.on("close", function() {
    var readableStream = fs.createReadStream("hello.txt", "utf8");
    readableStream.on("data", function(chunk){ 
        console.log(chunk);
    });
});
```

Что не отменяет того факта, что вы делаете что-то странное.

Comment: Скажи это автору курса (https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/2.10.php), что он делает что-то странное, а я всего лишь пытался воспроизвести его инструкции.